# Fragment caching is not working in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, cache-expiration

I am using rails 3 and fragment cache.
Here is my controller code(show method):

```
if request.format == 'pdf'
      render pdf: @design.slug, layout: 'application'
    else
      **expire_fragment('design_printed_by')**
      @design.add_evaluation(:viewed_count, 1, current_user) if current_user && !current_user.evaluated?(@design, :viewed_count)
      respond_with @design
    end
```

And here is my view file code(show.html.slim) :

```
- cache ['design_printed_by', @design], skip_digest: true do
          = render partial: 'printed_by', locals: { design: @design }
```

But when i add new record, this record is not display on page.
I don't know what i am missing.

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link may it help you.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching